# React Native Buttons not rendering in flexbox

Tags: button, react-native, flexbox

The following example is following the documentation provided by React-Native on Flexbox layouts and the button component. I'm trying to render a vertical list of buttons that are evenly spaced on the screen.

```
'use strict';
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Alert, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

class ClickerQuestion extends Component {
_handlePress(btnValue) {
    Alert.alert('Thanks, button "' + btnValue + '" has been pressed!');
}

render() {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: "column",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center"
            }}
        >
            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("B")}
                title="A"
                color="#214231"
            />

            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("B")}
                title="B"
                color="#214231"
            />

            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("C")}
                title="C"
                color="#214231"
            />

            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("D")}
                title="D"
                color="#214231"
            />

            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("E")}
                title="E"
                color="#214231"
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Unfortunately, this example only renders a blank screen. If I revert to static pixel values in CSS, I can render the page correctly. It's ideal to utilize Flexbox for responsive design, so let me know if I'm missing something in the above example.

```
'use strict';
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { Alert, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    margin: 60
},
text: {
    height: 30,
    fontSize: 25,
    padding: 5
}
});

class ClickerQuestion extends Component {
_handlePress(btnValue) {
    Alert.alert('Thanks, button "' + btnValue + '" has been pressed!');
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text} />
            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("A")}
                title="A"
                color="#214231"
            />

            <Text style={styles.text} />
            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("B")}
                title="B"
                color="#214231"
            />

            <Text style={styles.text} />
            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("C")}
                title="C"
                color="#214231"
            />

            <Text style={styles.text} />
            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("D")}
                title="D"
                color="#214231"
            />

            <Text style={styles.text} />
            <Button
                onPress={() => this._handlePress("E")}
                title="E"
                color="#214231"
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I've run the first code example and am getting 5 buttons showing up correctly, is ClickerQuestion contained in another outside View?

Comment: I think you just need to add style={{ flex: 1 }} to your buttons.